# XSD - I'm experiencing a strange behavior when using the abstract mechanism with substitution group from other namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following spml-example.xsd which defines a command element that contains action element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.myexample.com/command" xmlns:tns="http://www.myexample.com/command"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="Action" type="tns:ActionType" abstract="true" />

    <xs:complexType name="ActionType" abstract="true">
        <xs:attribute name="result" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Command">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="tns:Action" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

As you can see the action is abstract so concrete implementation substitutes it.
So I have two type of actions that extends this action:

 first one is spml-test-actions.xsd which defines a read action:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.myexample.com/actions/data"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.myexample.com/actions/data" xmlns:command="http://www.myexample.com/command"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.myexample.com/command"
        schemaLocation="../../spml-example.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="read" type="tns:readType"
        substitutionGroup="command:Action" />

    <xs:complexType name="readType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="command:ActionType">
                <xs:attribute name="a" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

second one is spml-local-actions.xsd which defines a popup action:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.myexample.com/actions/local"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.myexample.com/actions/local" xmlns:command="http://www.myexample.com/command"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.myexample.com/command"
        schemaLocation="../../spml-example.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="popup" type="tns:PopupType"
        substitutionGroup="command:Action" />

        <xs:complexType name="PopupType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="command:ActionType" >
                <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:float"/> 
                <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:float"/>
                <xs:attribute name="view" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**pay attention that these actions are in different namespaces**.

now I created the following xml instance and it works great:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Command xmlns="http://www.myexample.com/command" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:crud="http://www.myexample.com/actions/data"
    xmlns:local="http://www.myexample.com/actions/local"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.myexample.com/command spml-example.xsd 
    http://www.myexample.com/actions/data actions/data/spml-test-actions.xsd 
    http://www.myexample.com/actions/local actions/local/spml-local-actions.xsd">
    <local:popup/>
</Command>
```

but here is the quirk, now if I add the crud:read action it fails with the message **"cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'crud:read'. One of '{"http://
 www.myexample.com/command":Action}' is expected"**

This does not means that crud:read is not OK, cause if now I'll remove the local:popup action the xml will be valid again, i.e. it allows only action from one namespace to be added.

I do have a solution for this which is not correct by design, I can add to the spml-example.xsd imports of spml-test-actions.xsd and spml-local-actions.xsd.

please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem as it its said above. just need to go in eclipse to window -> preferences
and  then in xml validation prefernce unmark the  checkbox "honor all Xml Schema Locations".
see bug - [XML editor can't validate element of substitutionGroup](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=284272)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (using Saxon-EE 9.4 as the schema processor). It may be a bug in your schema processor, or something to do with the way it is configured.

Comment: yeah you're right I found the problem. I need to configure the xml validation in the preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what's missing from your question is how you validate the XML; unlike Michael, I think that your problem has nothing to do with your schema processor, but rather with how you validate your XML.

If your XML editor or whatever API you're using relies on the xsi:schemaLocation hints, then obviously what happens is that it only loads the first XML Schema file. You could easily play around by removing `http://www.myexample.com/command spml-example.xsd` from your schemaLocation hint; I guess what's going to happen then, member(s) of your substitution group from your first listed XSD, and from the imported ones, will work just fine; everything after will not.

If indeed you see this as the culprit, then what you can do to work around it - if you wish to stick with the schemaLocation hint - is to create an XSD that imports your crud and local XSDs (forget about `spml-example.xsd`) and use that XSD as your hint.

Otherwise, to get reasonable advice, you have to describe more of how you do your validation (I am guessing from the error message that is Java-based, Xerces most likely).